# How To bring text to front in html

Tags: html, css

I have website were the picture is over lapping the text but I want it the other way around.

```
<p>my text</p>
<img href="picture.jpg">
```

I got it so there both in the same place but the picture is still on top so far I've only tired flipping the order of the two lines of code but that did nothing

Comment: `href` is an invalid attribute for `img` element. use `src` instead. Since the `p` element is a block-level element, you need to change the position of your image to achieve this.

Comment: You haven't provided enough HTML/CSS to help you.  Post an actual reproducible example.  Even better if you post a jsfiddle link with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the z index property
here's a link that will help
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 4):

You can create a wrapper with `relative` [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and give the div `absolute` [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

```
.wrapper div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JCRQv/1/)

For further reading:

1. [Learn CSS Positioning in Ten Steps](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)
2. An alternative: [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Is *jsFiddle Demo* a key on keyboard? :) however, I'd like it.

Comment: @HashemQolami : It's not my idea.. It has become pretty common on SO lately :)

Answer (score 3):

Add some css to set the z index of the text to be greater than the image

HTML

```
<p id="text">my text</p>
<img id="image" src="picture.jpg">
```

CSS

```
#text{
    z-index: 1;
}

#image{
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Note you must position both elements in order for z-index to take effect. Use position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed

EDIT: Rahul rightly pointed out the original code used href instead of src. Updated as src is better practice

Comment: Dont use href attribute for image. Instead try to use src!!!

Comment: Excellent point. Updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add `z-index: 100;` after `position: fixed;` in your CSS.

And try to use `src` for image instead of `href`

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn how to use CSS's property called: `z-index`. Remember that you need to give `position` to the element you want to give `z-index` property.